# Improve ZF2 performance

Tags: performance, zend-framework2

How can I improve the performance of my ZF2 application in general?

I am currently using TemplateMap, ClassMap and Module config caching. But still I feel the application is quite slow. I check the performance with the Zend-Developer-Toolbar. The database only take up at twentieth of the run time. For example, a page loads within 420 ms and the database queries only take up about 20 ms of this time on my development machine. I am afraid this will kill the server when going live.

What can I do to improve the performance for my Zend Framework 2 application.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're taking pretty much everything into account that you can. Obviously there's always a couple of little Tricks and little things that you could use. For example: [`EdpSuperLuminal`](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpSuperluminal), but that's not the center of your problem.

Now, i don't know on what OS you are testing, all i can tell you is my experiences. From that point on, ZF2 + Windows + Xampp = effing slow. I don't know if that's the case, but due to the much higher amount of classes needed (read: files parsed on hdd) it just takes that much longer. SQL on local machine is much slower than a production one, too.

Whenever i switch from local to decelopment/staging, i run from ~500-750ms down to 100-150ms. And those numbers are without any sort of caching enabled. Turning on any sort of OpCode Cache (PHP 5.5 per default, APC on php 5.3 or lower) and you'll see your application skyrocket :)

Comment: Thanks Sam. Did not know about EdpSuperLuminal and will give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get EdpSuperLuminal to work properly. Always the page is aborted when adding the EDPSUPERLUMINAL_CACHE param to an url.

Answer (score 0):

> Install Defalte module on apache server to compress files and load the
>   heavy css and jquery files later using jquery
>   Set up expiration of the caching of the  images

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Add a script element as a child of the body
function loadScript(src) {
     var element = document.createElement("script");
     element.src = src;
     document.body.appendChild(element);
}
// Add a script element as a child of the body
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    loadScript("js/bootstrap.min.js");
    loadScript("js/respond.min.js");
}
// Check for browser support of event handling capability
 if (window.addEventListener)
     window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
     window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```